# Attribute error while running the Toolbox and Model

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, attributeerror

[image]When I am trying to run the following code

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.workspace = r"C:\Users\Rvg296\PycharmProjects\Lab6"
tbx=r"C:\Users\Rvg296\PycharmProjects\Lab6\UTD.tbx"
arcpy.ImportToolbox(tbx)
arcpy.Model_UTD()
print("Suitable areas file created")
arcpy.RemoveToolbox(tbx)
```

for making a model run and create shapefile in the output folder. 
I am receiving an error like

> C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\python.exe
>   C:/Users/Rvg296/PycharmProjects/Lab6/Lab6HW.py Traceback (most recent
>   call last):   File "C:/Users/Rvg296/PycharmProjects/Lab6/Lab6HW.py",
>   line 16, in 
>       arcpy.Model_UTD() AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Model_UTD'
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user please take the [tour].  Your screenshot shows a model in ArcGIS Pro, yet your python error is reporting ArcGIS 10.3.  ArcGIS Pro uses a different version of Python and accesses some parts of arcpy and tools differently.  You need to test using ArcGIS Pro's install of python.

Comment: I am currently using ArcGIS pro 1.1. How can I check the python version of this

Comment: With ArcGIS Pro 1.1 you have to install python separately.  From version 1.3 onward python is install as part of Pro.

Comment: Can I directly install Python 2.7 to the  ArcGIS Pro

Comment: No you cannot.  ArcGIS Pro uses Python 3.4 and its own version of arcpy.  It is different to Python 2.7 and Desktop 10.3's arcpy.  You'll need to install arcpy and python for ArcGIS Pro.

Answer (score 3):

Add the name of the toolbox you're importing as the second parameter.

If your toolbox is called UTD the import would be
`arcpy.ImportToolbox(tbx, 'UTD')`

Then you can call your function with `arcpy.UTD.Model_UTD()`

Comment: My Tool box is UTD and the tool is model.

Comment: Does `arcpy.UTD.model()` work?

Comment: No I am getting the same error again and again  'module' object has no attribute 'Model_UTD'

Comment: Are you still calling `Model_UTD` in your code?

Comment: The format is ToolName_ToolboxAlias(). But this is not working

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the toolbox?

Comment: Please check the added screenshot

Comment: For reference, @Evan is referring to the alternate form, by which you can use `arcpy.TBAlias.model_name()` instead of `arcpy.model_name_TBAlias()`. This is documented [here](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/geoprocessing_and_python/using-tools-in-python.htm) under Tool Organization in ArcPY: "All tools are available as functions on ArcPy but are also available in modules matching the toolbox alias name." Also, have you actually tried this solution? The toolbox _name_ and _alias_ are not the same thing.